# How do I rotate a text 45 degrees in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, rotation

I want a text field on my Crystal Report rotated 45 degrees. How can I accomplish this? Text field options only allows 90 and 270 degree rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crystal Report doesn't support this (at least not CR XI) but there is a workaround as long as the text is static:

- Insert a Excel spreadsheet as a new OLE-object.
- Type the text you want in cell A1.
- Apply wanted formatting and adjust height and width of the row and column.
- In Excel 2010: On the Show-tab, uncheck Guides, or you will get a grey frame around the text box.
- Resize the OLE object so that only the A1 cell is visible.